# Change font size for Ubuntu Document Viewer formfill

Tags: 20.04, fonts, pdf

Ubuntu 20.04 desktop comes with a default Document Viewer that also has a formfill mode.  I want to increase the font size when I fill in a pdf but I don’t see any option to do that.  Is there a way to increase the font size for formfill?  I only want to change the font size for what I type into the boxes, not the entire page.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to fill in a PDF form, and vary the font size.

My go-to tool for this is flpsed where you can import the pdf, type on it anywhere you want.

In the top left corner of flpsed, you can choose the font-size to use when entering text. You have several sizes to pick from, and you don't have to use the same size for all your text.

**sudo apt install flpsed**

https://flpsed.org/flpsed.html

When you finish editing, save the PDF with a different name to avoid clobbering your original.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll install it and try it out.